# Boost serial write wrong data send

Tags: boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm using boost asio serial functions to send data over serial port. I have used it in the past and it worked as ı wanted. But now it behaves strange. This is the code which i used to send data :

```
int data = 97;    //represents 'a'
string sendThis = "0";
sendThis[0] = (char)data;
cout<<sendThis<<" "<<data<<endl;
boost::asio::write(serial,boost::asio::buffer(sendThis,1));
```

Here is the problem: When i send data which is bigger than 128 i get exactly what i sent. But when i try to send characters which is less than 128; on the other side i get added 128 which is 225 for 'a'. Because of this problem i always get between 128 and 255. I tried different send methods and result is always same. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: There is some information missing from your question. How is the serial port set up? How many data bits?

Comment: Baudrate 115200 and I didnt change other values. So I think it is default values 8 bit, no parity. Tomorrow i will try with setting them up by myself. There may be something wrong with default values.

Comment: I set the data bits option and it worked. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Problem was data bits options as previously mentioned in the comment. So **never ever trust default values** especially in cases it can protect previous state. So I think somehow data bits option changed and it always used that value. I set the option by summary:

```
serial_port_base::character_size x(8);
serial_port serial(io,"COM58");
serial.set_option(x);
```

After that it worked. Than I tried again by commenting setting the option. And it again worked. So I suppose it protects previous states. So be careful with default values. **They may not be default anymore.**